# Getting task release could not be found for edeliver

Tags: elixir, release, distillery, edeliver

I have an elixir application with 3 umbrella projects. I am trying to automate their releases via distellary and edeliver.

I am able to create a release by running this command:

*mix release --verbose --env="production" --name="se_example"*

However when I run the following:
*mix edeliver build release production --verbose*

It compiles the app but later throws this error when creating release:

> -----> Generating release using mix to generate release
>
> ** (Mix) The task "release" could not be found

I am new to elixir and distillery / edeliver world so was wondering if I am missing something in this flow.

Following is my .deliver/config file:

```
PRODUCTION_HOSTS="elixir-build"
PRODUCTION_USER="meraj"
DELIVER_TO="/home/meraj/se_example_build"

# For *Phoenix* projects, symlink prod.secret.exs to our tmp source
pre_erlang_get_and_update_deps() {
  local _prod_secret_path="/home/meraj/se_example_build/prod.secret.exs"
  if [ "$TARGET_MIX_ENV" = "prod" ]; then
    __sync_remote "
      ln -sfn '$_prod_secret_path' '$BUILD_AT/config/prod.secret.exs'
      ln -sfn '$_prod_secret_path' '$BUILD_AT/apps/se/config/prod.secret.exs'
    "
  fi
}
```

And here is rel/config.exs file:

```
Path.join(["rel", "plugins", "*.exs"])
|> Path.wildcard()
|> Enum.map(&Code.eval_file(&1))

use Mix.Releases.Config,
    default_release: :default,
    default_environment: Mix.env()

environment :dev do
  set dev_mode: true
  set include_erts: false
  set cookie: :"P@/3]_>gLBMM9c@&aRUg>lkN)<q6Z$0`ZM_/./!8N_/*1Fx:toH9n~I5_=O&=>$:"
end

environment :prod do
  set include_erts: true
  set include_src: false
  set cookie: :"BD:?3o^s?_Yn4SV%s.;@A>Sva*A}s5NbEC[&.qBMhA.*6^?ElspFmoF%GKX]:[En"
end

release :se_example do
  set version: "0.1.0"
  set applications: [
    :runtime_tools,
    se: :permanent,
    se_stats: :permanent,
    se_web: :permanent
  ]
end
```

Comment: It sounds like you do not have distillery installed. Can you show your dependencies as listed in your mix.exs file?

Comment: Following is my mix.exs:


`defmodule Se.Example.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      apps_path: "apps",
      start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:distillery, "~> 1.5.2"},
      {:edeliver, "~> 1.4.6"}
    ]
  end
end
`

Comment: Did you actually run `mix deps.get` after adding distillery as a dependency?

Comment: Yes. I have run. To made sure, I re-run it and tried again but with same result.

Comment: @MerajRasool did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had same error and found solution (at least in my situation), answered in another related topic here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53950284/6371774

TLDR: point your branch explicitly and make sure, that folder `/rel/` under git and committed:

```
$ mix edeliver build release --branch=feature/deploy
```